# How do I map the largest files\folders in Artifactory

Tags: maven, artifactory

It's often hard to map the most storage heavy parts in my mvn repo.

I suspect that most of my space is occupied by unnecessary artifacts or snapshots.

How can I retrieve a sorted list (from large to small) of all the folders in Artifactory (Maven repo)?

I've looked at Jfrog api and cli guides but was unable to find straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Artifactory's AQL to get what you're after.
for example, get all Items in a repository, that where created over 30 days ago, sorted by descending Size (disk space):

```
    items.find(
{
            "repo":"my-local-repo",
            "$or":[
                {
                    "$and":[
                     {
                        "created":{"$before":"30d"}
                     }
                            ]
                }
                ]
    }
).sort({"$desc" : ["size"]})
```

You can use Artifactory's REST api to send your AQL query. 
You can read more about AQL [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language), an "tune" your query to find what you are after.

note: though you can use AQL with the CLI, sorting is currently not supported in CLI's AQL queries so use the REST API instead.

HTH,
Or

Comment: Haven't find any examples in the documentation. How should one structure the REST API, which method?how the header / body should look like?

Would you mind to include example (curl/python/java) so I can accept your answer. (mine solution is working, yours looks more elegant but I'd like to verify it's working before accepting it)

Comment: 1. REST API documentation here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SEARCHES . the header is a simple authentication header as documented here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Authentication .  the body of the post is the JSON i provided in my answer.   2. You can now use JFrog's CLI with SORT and LIMIT as well, which might be a lot easier to use, as documented here - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles

Comment: And here's an example curl for all of the above:      curl -X POST -u MyUser:MyPassword -H "content-type: text/plain" -d 'items.find({"repo":" my-local-repo","$or":[{"$and":[{"created":{"$before":"30d"}}]}]}).sort({"$desc" : ["size"]}).limit(3)' http://myartifactoryserver:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql

Answer (score 3):

I've came up with [small python script](https://github.com/borisovano/arti-repo-map) that does produce such a list.

**Example:**

```
python ./arti_parse.py -r www.artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/storage/libs-snapshot-local?list&deep=1&listFolders=1&mdTimestamps=1 -u myuser -p mypass
```

Will produce the following output:

`-- Some output omitted --
com/mycompany/tools/platform        - 64.8GiB  (Total: 420.9GiB)
com/mycompany/tools/ba              - 71.2GiB  (Total: 492.1GiB)
com/mycompany/common/server         - 115.4GiB (Total: 607.5GiB)
com/mycompany/common/client         - 169.7GiB (Total: 777.2GiB)
com/mycompany/common/Automation     - 295.4GiB (Total: 1.0TiB)`